# Disable StyleCop's SA1600 rule for internal interfaces

Tags: .net, visual-studio, coding-style, code-analysis, stylecop

**StyleCop.Analyzers**: 1.1.118

My **stylecop.json:**

```
 {
      "$schema":
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
      "settings": {
        "documentationRules": {
          "companyName": "ShapeCrawler",
          "documentInternalElements": false
        }
      }
    }
```

**Sample:**

[image]

Is it possible to disable "SA1600: Elements should be documented" rule for **internal** interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, internal interfaces are visible to all types within the assembly, and any assemblies that have a "friend" relationship with it via the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. It's generally a good idea to document public members of internal types (including interfaces) unless you have a truly compelling reason not to; at the very least, you'll benefit from IntelliSense documentation at the point of call.

Having said that, if you're determined not to document them, wrap the type in the following:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
[Your code here]
#pragma warning enable 1591
```

Comment: "internal interfaces are public" Hmm, didn't know about that.

Comment: @AdamShakhabov A better term would have been "visible to". I'll update the comment to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **"documentExposedElements":  false** keyvalue pair in your stylecop.json file fix SA1600 issue.

```
{
  // ACTION REQUIRED: This file was automatically added to your project, but it
  // will not take effect until additional steps are taken to enable it. See the
  // following page for additional information:
  //
  // https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/EnableConfiguration.md

  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "documentationRules": {
      "companyName": "PlaceholderCompany",
      "documentExposedElements":  false //Add this
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.